# Fade-in module content when it's open

Tags: jquery

I want to show a module when a button is clicked (done) and then fade-in it's content. When the module gets closed must work again, obviously.

```
$('#btn-openList').on('click', function(){
    $( this ).toggleClass('layout-color-subBase');
    $( "#overlay-list" ).toggleClass('overlay--hidden');
    $( "#overlay-listContent" ).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**.overlay--hidden** is a class with "display:none"

Comment: make snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: A jsfiddle could be easy to implement and help use to understand your problem ;)

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` at question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [`jQuery.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) on your `$( "#overlay-listContent" )` element ?

```
$('#btn-openList').on('click', function(){
    $( this ).toggleClass('layout-color-subBase');
    $( "#overlay-list" ).toggleClass('overlay--hidden');
    $( "#overlay-listContent" ).toggle('slow');
});
```

If you want your animation to be more customizable, you can use toggle on [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

> ### From jQuery.animate() documentation
>
> In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings
>   'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'. These shortcuts allow for custom hiding
>   and showing animations that take into account the display type of the
>   element. In order to use jQuery's built-in toggle state tracking, the
>   'toggle' keyword must be consistently given as the value of the
>   property being animated.

```
$('#btn-openList').on('click', function(){
    $( this ).toggleClass('layout-color-subBase');
    $( "#overlay-list" ).toggleClass('overlay--hidden');

    var currentOpacity = $('#overlay-listContent').css('opacity');
    $( "#overlay-listContent" ).animate({
        'opacity': 1-currentOpacity
    }, 300);
});
```

And css

```
#overlay-listContent {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's fine, but is there a way to set an opacity animation instead of axis's resizing? I get an ugly animation right now

Comment: You can use jQuery.animate() with opacity property and 'toggle' in properties :D. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have opacity 0 in #overlay-listContent (vía styles) and doesn't works :( I delete the opacity rule and it works but backwards, obviously. So, it works backwards but not the way that it must to work